# adding drbd to an existing lvm

Tags: lvm, drbd

I'm going to add drbd to an existing LVM, I want to keep LVM data. I follow this post: http://lists.linbit.com/pipermail/drbd-user/2009-February/011464.html

what I already did

- stopped kvm virtual machine using LVM
- backup of LVM data with dd

  ```
  dd if=/dev/server1_vg0/res of=/root/res.dump bs=512K
  ```
- config file for drbd resource

  ```
  resource res {
    device    /dev/drbd1;
    disk      /dev/server1_vg0/res;
    flexible-meta-disk internal;
    on server1 {
      address   x.x.x.x:xxxx;
    }
    on server2 {
      address   x.x.x.x:xxxx;
    }
  }
  ```
- growed 5MB LVM to fit drbd metadata

  ```
  lvextend -L +5m /dev/server1_vg0/res
  ```

Now I see this warning when I do

```
[root@server1 ~]# drbdadm create-md res
md_offset 21483220992
al_offset 21483188224
bm_offset 21482528768

Found some data

 ==> This might destroy existing data! <==

Do you want to proceed?
[need to type 'yes' to confirm]    

Operation canceled.
```

will this command destroy LVM data? what those offsets mean? (md/al/bm_offset)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was safe to do:

LV ending before adding 5MB:

```
[root@server1 ~]# blockdev --getsize64 /dev/server1_vg0/res
21474836480
```

so, all drbd offsets start after LV data, I proceeded and it worked fine